# Android HTTP POST response doesn't response

Tags: android, apache, http, post, connection

I can't tell why my code doesn't get a response to a post request. This is the documentation of the server:

Web services for **EMT-REST** *(JSON)* Access.
    All service Requests are called as POST, so all parameters should be added into body request.
    Responses are JSON formatted text.

    All method requests require an *idClient* and *passKey*, those values are provided by EMT upon request.

**URL base is https://openbus.emtmadrid.es:9443/emt-proxy-server/last/**

GetArriveStop   POST

${ServerURL}/geo/GetArriveStop.php

Gets bus arrive info to a target stop

Request

idClient    API client identifier   string

passKey API client password string

idStop  Stop id string
statistics  Private use (do not set)    string

cultureInfo EN|ES Language for response string

Response

arrives List of Arrives List of Arrive

Finally, this is my Android code to execute it:

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.hmkcode.android.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    EditText etName;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute("https://openbus.emtmadrid.es:9443/emt-proxy-server/last/geo/GetArriveStop.php");
}


    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


            return POST(urls[0]);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent and received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            etName.setText(result); //editText from layout
       }
    }


    public static String POST(String url){
        Log.i("METHOD POST INICIATED", "METHOD POST");
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("idClient","EMT.SERVICIOS.EMTJSONBETA");
            jsonObject.accumulate("passKey", "4F4EEB75-A822-41E3-817B-AB301D5DA321");
            jsonObject.accumulate("idStop", "488");
            jsonObject.accumulate("cultureInfo", "ES");


            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            // ** Alternatives way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib 

            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            Log.i("HTTP EXECUTION", "right before line httpclient.exeute");
            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            Log.i("AFTER HTTP EXECUTION", "right before line hhtpclient.exeute");
            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            //inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            //if(inputStream != null){
                Log.i("CONVERT INPUT", "convertInputStreamToString");
                //result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            //}else{
                Log.i("NO INPUT", "result = did not work!");
                //result = "Did not work!";
            //}

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }
}
```

it doesn't continue anymore after this line of code
// 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

and I don't know why.

I have tried it with another server as an example and it worked fine, maybe I'm missing something in the header. Full documentation of the server: http://blog.emtmadrid.es/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/API-REST-JSON-v-1.1.rar

Comment: You are sending the parameters as a json array. Where did you read that in the documentation? Try to send the parameters as normal name value pairs. But application/json is there... Well i don't know...

Comment: It does continue but in the catch block. You display a Toast in onPostExecute stating `"Data Sent and received!"` but you are not checking if that is true. Add a statement `result += "Exception: " +  e.getLocalizedMessage();' in the catch block. You should have seen the message already in your logcat though.

Comment: I did that and checked it in another network and I received the following Exception : "no peer certificate". After a while looking into it I found this [pdf](http://www.mcafee.com/us/resources/white-papers/wp-defeating-ssl-cert-validation.pdf) that solved the problem with this exception in most cases (It seems to be pretty usual in Android).

Comment: But did it solve it for you? I think this is not the way to go. If you want to use https than get your own certificale and use ssl.

Comment: yes it does work now, there isn't any problem with the connection. I suppose is not the best way to avoid this Exception but I don't now much to get an idea of how to correct it. The documentation does not talk about certificates so I suppose is a client-side issue.